# How To Change Navigation Bar Color?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Using Xamarin Forms Pcl & Prism Library
in side APP.CS

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
   //Initialize();

   InitializeComponent();

   NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/MainPage");
}

protected override void RegisterTypes()
{
    Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
    Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainPage,MainPageViewModel>
    ("MainPage");
}
```

inside MainPage.Xaml

```
Title="Main Page" 
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True"
NavigationPage.BarTextColor="Black"
NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColor="Red"
```

but it Never Changes the NavigationBar Color.

Comment: This is actually not related to Prism. For reference: the relevant part for Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4 for iOS can be found [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/release-2.3.4/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/NavigationRenderer.cs#L559). So that should actually work, while it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest opening an issue on [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/) with Xamarin. That doesn't actually work currently in a Xamarin Forms app without Prism. If you are using a single style in your app you could just add the following style to your App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <!-- Application resource dictionary -->
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
            <Setter Property="HasNavigationBar" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Otherwise I might suggest implementing a NavigationPage that is `INavigatingAware` and use the NavigationParameters to help it figure out what styling you need to use.

Comment: but  <Application> changed to <prism:PrismApplication>.

Comment: i changed the color from style.xml

Comment: If you're using PrismApplication you would need that one change.

Answer (score 0):

I created my own Navigation page

```
public class CustomNav : NavigationPage
 {
      public CustomNav() 
       {
            //here you can set all you styles 
       } 
  }
```

And when registering

```
Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<CustomNav>("NavigationPage");
```

So when I use I can reference it NavigationPage

Comment: This isn't wrong but should only be used if you require multiple Navigation Pages in your app that each require different styles. It's far better to set a global style in your App Resources.

Answer (score 0):

with Prism follow this link: https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/navigation/navigation-basics.html where T in "Register" section is your custom NavigationPage (in the example below `AppInfoNavPage`) where you set the various attributes in the constructor like this

```
public partial class AppInfoNavPage : NavigationPage
{
    public AppInfoNavPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BarBackgroundColor = App.Data.DarkBlue;
        BarTextColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```